# replacing lines with elements from a list

Tags: python

I am reading a file and looking for a particular string in it like this :

```
template = open('/temp/template.txt','r')
new_elements = ["movie1","movies2"]

for i in template.readlines():
    if "movie" in i:
        print "replace me"
```

This is all good but I would like to replace the lines that are found with the elements from "new_elements" . I make the assumption that the number of found strings will always match the number of elements in the "new_elements" list . I just don't know how to iterate over the new_elements whilst looking for lines to replace .

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to make `new_elements` an iterator:

```
template = open('/temp/template.txt','r')
new_elements = iter(["movie1","movies2"])

for i in template.readlines():
    if "movie" in i:
        print "replace line with", new_elements.next()
```

You haven't said how you want to do the replacement- whether you want to write it to a new file, for example- but this will fit into whatever code you use.

Comment: Good solution but `next(new_elements)` is better now.

Comment: @jamylak: Interesting. I use them somewhat interchangeably, though I like the latter for being more OO- do you have any links I can read about why `next(itr)` is better than `itr.next()`?

Comment: `next` allows using a default to pad, instead of raising `StopIteration`, which may be nice in some cases.  they seem to be more or less equivalent otherwise

Comment: @DavidRobinson It's being changed for Py3.x where `.next` is no longer available, here's a link: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is pretty simple:  the [`.pop()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) method of lists.  This will get the next entry in the list, and remove it; your next call to that function will return the next item.  No need to do any iteration at all.

Without a parameter, it will pop the last element.  If you want to pop the first, you can use `new_elements.pop(0)`, although this will be slower than popping from the end.

Comment: Good solution, but slower than an iterator since it has to change the list each time (and unless I'm mistaken, popping from the front of a Python list is slower than popping from the end).

Comment: It is slower, but I find it conceptually clearer and would use this in a situation where it wasn't going to be called a lot (a simple ETL script, or similar).  I will make a note about the comparative speed.